# Cygwin terminal cannot show the contents of unicode text file correctly

Tags: cygwin, unicode

I have a text file with Urdu text. I use the cat command to view the content, but I see distorted digits and symbols like text. How can I view the text correctly?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide some example text.

Comment: 1) Either there is an encoding problem 2) or you use a font which simply doesn't contain the Urdu characters. The problem is probably not in the Cygwin, but in the terminal program.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you need to use / select an appropriate font that supports unicode if you already have your language settings set as per whats outlined on: https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html

```
echo $LANG
# en_GB.UTF-8
```

Within your `cygin` window under `Options`>`Text`>`Font Select...` you can choose `Courier New` that should display all supported characters.